One of the biggest companies I wrote to was or is Alaska Airlines?
Here is a question test:

Fill in the blanks with suitable forms of the verb:
I kept going. Whenever I heard of businesses using plastic, I’d send an email. One of the biggest companies I wrote to _______(be) Alaska Airlines.

The only answer given by the exercise book is 'was'. But we can use the present simple to talk about something that is always true. Whenever the author wrote to the company, it is surely Alaska Airlines. Also, here is another sentence:

The guy who wrote to me is Scottish and currently in jail for murder in Walla Walla, he said thanks for putting me in your book.  ----The Guardian - Books

So I wonder if 'is' works well here. If so, is there any difference between the use of is and was?

Many native speakers would consider "is Alaska Airlines"   sub-standard here:

One of the biggest companies I wrote to is Alaska Airlines.

Here are forms  everyone accepts:

One of the biggest companies I wrote to was Alaska Airlines.
One of the biggest companies I have written to is Alaska Airlines.

The grammatical rule has nothing to do with whether the company still goes by that name.

Either "is" or "was" is correct.
As the writing is in the past, many would say "was".
But Alaska Airlines presumably still exists and is still the biggest company that you wrote to. So the "eternal present" "is" is also correct.
A fluent English speaker would take both sentences to mean the same thing.
It's probably better to use "was" because Alaska Airlines is not really an "eternal present" like the law of gravity. They could have gone broke since you wrote to them, or have changed their name, or been bought out by another airline, etc.

In the Alaska Airlines case, if the writing is past and the company did not change name, both was and is are correct:

One of the biggest companies I wrote to was (or is) Alaska Airlines.

If the company is no longer called Alaska Airlines, only was is possible.
Edit
In the Scottish guy case, if he is still alive,
both was and is are correct:

The guy who wrote to me was (or is) Scottish ...

If he is no longer alive,  only was is possible.

Once a Scotsman, always a Scotsman! I don't think you can change your birthplace at will... wait, here we go, someone will tell me it's possible. I'll ignore it. But if you learn of his death then you can certainly write "was".

@Mari-LouA - surely no true Scotsman (etc)?

Thanks, @Mari-Lou A.  I've corrected that part.
